# Python request SSLError bad handshakes

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, postman

I've successfully made a request to a site on Postman, but when I copy the Python code and execute it, it gave me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 366, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 491, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dkmh/login.asp (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dkmh/login.asp (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))
```

Here is the full code (I have removed the original URL)

```
import requests

url = "https://xxx/login.asp"

payload = 'chkSubmit=ok&txtLoginId=19020055&txtPassword=qj28r8&txtSel=1'
headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'Origin': 'https://xxx',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Referer': 'https://xxx/login.asp',
  'Accept-Language': 'vi-VN,vi;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.1781562536.1609987797; ASPSESSIONIDAQDQQQSC=MDJHCACBKMNBFFLOGABMCGEA; UnivId=; intUserLogedin=92573; selab=intUserRef=92573; first=PortalModule%5F376; intUserLogedin=92573; selab=intUserRef=92573; UnivId=; first=PortalModule%5F376'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

According to my check, the TLS version of the site is 1.0. I tried the script with python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, tried to install requests[security], but none of the above actions worked!

The output of SSLLabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=daotao.vnu.edu.vn

Comment: This can be anything. Server requiring weak ciphers like RC4 or 3DES, needing a client certificate, incompatibility with modern TLS stacks, ... - impossible to tell based on this information. If the server is public it would help to provide the URL or the full output of [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). If you are in control of the server look into the server side log files for hints what the problem might be.

Comment: I've add the link to the SSLLabs analysis at the end of the question. The website is my university's site

Answer (score 0):

Holy sh.t, the server is totally insecure and hopelessly broken:

[image]

The only cipher supported which is only weak and not already insecure is 3DES-CBC:

[image]

But, since this cipher is weak it is not supported by common builds of OpenSSL - which is the base for SSL in Python. Is is usable in older version of Python or with special builds of OpenSSL though if explicitly enabled.

See [How to work with Python requests with hosts only supporting TLS 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55752587/3081018) or [Requests failing to connect to a TLS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141655/requests-failing-to-connect-to-a-tls-server) on how to enable this cipher from Python - as long as it is build into the underlying OpenSSL library.

Comment: Thank you. It gave me "Caused by SSLError(SSLError('No cipher can be selected.',),)" after following the threads you have given. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
In addition, could you specify a python version which supported 3DES-CBC cipher, or a link to where I can consult to create a "special build of OpenSSL"?

Comment: @HoàngTùng: There is no specific Python version, it is a question of OpenSSL build options and then compiling Python with this specific build of OpenSSL. Details depend on your OS. For example I have an older version of Anaconda Python 3.6.3 lying around which comes with OpenSSL 1.0.2 and which still supports 3DES.

Comment: I have followed the following [https://superuser.com/questions/1179309/how-to-enable-3des-ssl-ciphers-for-openssl-1-0-2k](guide) about enabling 3DES SSL Cipher on a custom OpenSSL build. Howerver, the same message "No cipher can be selected" still showed up

Comment: @HoàngTùng: not only do you need an OpenSSL with 3DES enabled but Python also needs to be compiled against it in order to use - see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+compile+with+custom+openssl) for various instructions on how to do it.